# Plot a curve on a lattice

Tags: plotting, labeling

How do I plot a 2d curve and label lattice points to one side of it?

I want to plot the curve $f[x]=\frac{1}{x}$, and draw a solid red dot at every lattice point in the following set:
$$\{(m,n)\in \mathbb N^2\colon mn\geq 1\}$$

Comment: Make a lattice with `Tuples`, filter it with `Select`, plot with `ListPlot`, combine it with the curve using `Show`.

Comment: You can add something like `Epilog -> {Red, Point[Flatten[Array[List, {5, 5}], 1]]}` to your plot.

Answer (score 5):

In V10.1 or later, you can use [`CoordinateBoundingBoxArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundingBoxArray.html) to generate the lattice.

```
With[{m = 5},
  Plot[1/x, {x, 0, m},
    Epilog -> {
      Red, PointSize[Medium],
      Point[Flatten[CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{{1, 1}, {m, m}}], 1]]},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    PlotRange -> {0, m},
    PlotRangePadding -> .15,
    Frame -> True]]
```

[image: plot]